# REST WS (in jersey) reading a JSON from android application

Tags: java, android, json, character-encoding, jersey

I have reading some questions over this tags, but I can't solve my problem

I have a RESTful Web Service using Jersey 1.X version (1.19 according to Maven repository) in which I try to read a JSON Object from an Android application. The problem is due to when I send a JSON whose fields has any character like:

> á 
>   é
>   í
>   ö...
>   I want to repeat I am able to read a JSON without these specials characters. I try adding charset=UTF-8 and setting headers but it doesn't work.

Apache console give this log

```
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
GRAVE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@286c42cb; line: 1, column: 35]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1432)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:385)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._reportInvalidOther(Utf8StreamParser.java:2802)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._reportInvalidOther(Utf8StreamParser.java:2809)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._decodeUtf8_3fast(Utf8StreamParser.java:2632)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._finishString2(Utf8StreamParser.java:1950)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._finishString(Utf8StreamParser.java:1899)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.getText(Utf8StreamParser.java:276)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:26)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:13)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2695)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1308)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:490)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:86)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

ago 27, 2015 1:19:01 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [RESTWebServiceAndroid] en el contexto con ruta [/RESTWebServiceAndroid] lanzó la excepción [org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@286c42cb; line: 1, column: 35]] con causa raíz
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@286c42cb; line: 1, column: 35]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1432)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:385)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._reportInvalidOther(Utf8StreamParser.java:2802)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._reportInvalidOther(Utf8StreamParser.java:2809)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._decodeUtf8_3fast(Utf8StreamParser.java:2632)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._finishString2(Utf8StreamParser.java:1950)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser._finishString(Utf8StreamParser.java:1899)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.Utf8StreamParser.getText(Utf8StreamParser.java:276)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:26)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:13)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2695)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1308)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:490)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:86)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And android logcat says me

```
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.63 - Informe de Error</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>Estado HTTP 500 - org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22</h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Informe de Excepción</p><p><b>mensaje</b> <u>org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22</u></p><p><b>descripción</b> <u>El servidor encontró un error interno que hizo que no pudiera rellenar este requerimiento.</u></p><p><b>excepción</b> <pre>javax.servlet.ServletException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x22
```

My Java Object in WS is:

```
public class UsuarioDB {
//Atributos del objeto Usuario, para cada usuario registrado en nuestra base de datos
String dni;
String nombre;
String apellidos;
String correo;
String movil;
String username;
String password;

//getters and setters (it hides this part to make this shortest)
```

}

Web service code

```
@Path("/ws")
public class PrincipalWS {
 @POST
    @Path("/newuser")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    public Response createUserInJSON1(UsuarioDB newuser){
        System.out.println("Estoy en WS");
        String result = "Usuario registrado : " + newuser;
        System.out.println(result);

        return Response.status(201).entity(result).header("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8").build();    
    } 
}
```

And Finally mi Android client

```
public boolean registraUsuario(String DNI, String nombre, String apellidos, String email, String movil, String username, String password){

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://"+URL_conexion+"/rest/ws/newuser");
        post.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        try {
            JSONObject jpost = new JSONObject();
            jpost.put("dni", DNI);
            jpost.put("nombre", nombre);    
            jpost.put("apellidos", apellidos);
            jpost.put("correo", email);
            jpost.put("movil", movil);
            jpost.put("username", username);
            jpost.put("password", password);

            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jpost.toString());
            entity.setContentEncoding("UTF-8");
            entity.setContentType("application/json");

            HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(post);
            resultado = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        return true; // no ha habido ningun error
    }
```

I have a mess with this. Its driving me crazy.
I hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to create a request entity by `new StringEntity(jpost.toString(), "UTF-8")`?

Comment: @Sasha Salayou It works correctly! Thanks you so much! =)